# Division of 0 while solving an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Source: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IoV.aspx, Example 2.

> Determine all possible solutions to the following IVP.
> $$y'=y^{\frac{1}{3}}, \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\ y(0)=0$$

To solve this ODE the author divides both sides by $y^{\frac{1}{3}}$. This seems wrong to me. We want a solution in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, and $y^{\frac{1}{3}}(0)=0$ therefore we would be dividing by $0$ at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is correct, that's why you at first examine the zero function and find that it is a solution.

Now the right side is not Lipschitz at $y=0$, so you have to consider the possibility of other solutions. Thus assume that $y(t)\ne 0$ for $t>0$. Then the division is not by zero at points $t>0$.

A similar treatment can be done for $t<0$, it turns out that there are no solutions but the zero solution that end up in $y(0)=0$ on the negative half-axis.

Comment: What guarantees that those solutions you find by assuming $y(t)\neq 0$ for $t>0$ will satisfy the differential equation when extended to include $x=0$?

Comment: That you will have to check afterwards. Here it is sufficient that $\lim_{t\to 0}y(t)=0$, the DE itself needs to be satisfied only for $t>0$. Note that the DE itself does not have a singularity.

Comment: Why does it have to be satisfied only for $t>0$, shouldn't it also have to be satisfied for $t<0$?

Comment: Oh, this was an association from another question. Well, in any interpretation of the right side one can only have $y(t)=0$ for $t\le 0$, so that this is trivial to extend.